# XJC non-transient non-serializable instance field data

Tags: java, date, serializable, transient

After generating java classes I received:

```
public class myClass {

@XmlElement(name = "Data", required = true)
@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar data;
@XmlElement(name = "Time", required = true)
protected XMLGregorianCalendar time;
.........
```

FindBugs warns that myClass defines non-transient non-serializable instance field data.
Is it warning acceptable or need to fix?
Thanks.

Comment: Running FindBugs across generated code is pretty pointless - there's generally not much you can do about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine to ignore this warning, these are special classes designed for a different serialization method (XML). You might as well set findbugs to ignore the entire generated package.